# .NET C# Linq get list of string from concatenation of two properties of list of objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Employee objects, where each employee have a Name property and an Address property.
What Linq could I use to obtain a list of strings where each string is made by the concatenation of Employee.Name + "_" + Employee.Address?

```
public class Employee {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name { get; set; }
    public int Address { get; set; }
}

List<Employee> emplist = new List<Employee>();
emplist.Add(new Employee() {
    Id=1,
    Name = "John Doe",
    Address = "Some Street 5"
});
emplist.Add(new Employee() {
    Id = 2,
    Name = "Jack Daniels",
    Address = "Main Avenue 43"
});
emplist.Add(new Employee() {
    Id = 3,
    Name = "Jane Murphy",
    Address = "BlahBlah 123"
});
```

And I want to get a list of strings, like
"John Doe_Some Street 5",
"Jack Daniels_Main Avenue 43",
"Jane Murphy_BlahBlah 123"
etc

Comment: Since you didn't post any code it's hard to tell, but it will probably involve `Select`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
employees.Select(emp => string.Concat(emp.Name, "_", emp.Address))
```

This will return an IEnumerable containing the concatenated string for each employee.

Make sure you've got `using System.Linq;` at the top of your file.

Comment: Why the `Concat` over an interpolated string or `+` operators?

Comment: One benefit - it accepts a collection of strings - if you you have a list of strings, you can append them to each other. Would require a loop otherwise.

Comment: Strings in C# are immutble. I'm not sure if Concat alleviates this problem. Using a `StringBuilder`can improve performance from a memory perspective.

Comment: `Concat` is implemented to do only one allocation, yes.

Answer (score 0):

with this is code,you can create a new field called address

```
emplist.Select(c => new { Name_address = string.Format("{0}_{1}", c.Name, c.Address) });
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on some of the comments and suggestions among these, I add some example code here to solve the same problem for completeness.

If you use String interpolation, you could do it like this:

```
var employeesNamesAndAddressesFormatted = emplist.Select(e => $"{e.Name}_{e.Address}");
foreach (var emp in employeesNamesAndAddressesFormatted){
        Console.WriteLine(emp);
}
```

This gives:

```
John Doe_Some Street 5
Jack Daniels_Main Avenue 43
Jane Murphy_BlahBlah 123
```

To use StringBuilder instead to accumulate the strings, you could do it like this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
emplist.Select(e => sb.AppendLine($"{e.Name}_{e.Address}")).ToList();
Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
```

Strings are immutable, but using StringBuilder allows you instead to add strings using the same string builder instance. If this was a very large array, it would be a more interesting solution, saving some memory.